# Error: A value of type 'x' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

I'm getting the following error during compiling:

lib/main.dart:40:34: Error: A value of type 'Clubinfo' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

The files sponsor.dart and clubinfo.dart seems to be the same.  I've just replaced

```
Sponsor->Clubinfo
sponsor->clubinfo
Sponsors->Clubinfos
sponsors->clubinfos


        final List<Widget> screens = [
        Home(), Events(), Players(), Clubinfo(),Sponsors(),
        ];
```

The error is coming from this line. 
Clubinfo is a copy of sponsors.dart but only sponsors is working.
I've changed the names in the dart file.
lib/main.dart:40:34: Error: A value of type 'Clubinfo' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

Comment: What is the value `ClubInfo()` returning?

Comment: Probably Clubinfo isn't extending neither Stateless nor Stateful widgets

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake of me.
It must be Clubinfos() instead of Clubinfo().
Thanks for the support.